# An element pops up over another element in telephone size

Tags: html, css, list, input

[image]

This is what it is supposed to be the search and under it the list but when I try to write something I have this problem

[image]

the list pops ower the search, could you tell me please how to solve this problem

**Code:**

```css
    .navigation{
      position: fixed;
      left: -32rem;
      width: 40rem;
      height: 100%;
      background:linear-gradient(to top,    rgb(0, 0, 0, .9),rgb(0, 0, 0, .9));
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      transition: left .8s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
      z-index: 4;
    
    }
    .navigation-serch{
      position: relative;
      top: 10rem;
    }
    .navigation-list{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    height: 28rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
        <div class="navigation-headin">
            <form class="navigation-serch">
                <input type="text" class="navigation-search-input" placeholder="Search">
                <button name="navigation-search" class="navigation-search-btn"> 
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li class="navigation-item"> <a href="#" name="navigation-item " class="navigation-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-item"> <a href="#" name="navigation-item " class="navigation-link">About us</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-item"> <a href="#" name="navigation-item " class="navigation-link">Rooms</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-item"> <a href="#" name="navigation-item " class="navigation-link">Events</a></li>
            <li class="navigation-item"> <a href="#" name="navigation-item " class="navigation-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="copy-right">
            <p>&copy; 2021 Sunset Lodge. All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Not spending the time for a full-fledged answer, sorry, but I can tell you that your problem is the `.navigation-serch { position: relative; top:10rem; }`.  Doing this, the space the element takes up on the page remains the same (as in it'll not affect other elements), it'll just appear `10 rem` further down and overlap content in the same context. But you actually WANT it to push the menu down, so I find it much more likely that you want a `padding-top:10rem;` or `margin-top:10rem;` instead of messing with the positioning here.

Comment: @ippi I think is right  for your problem as posed, but could you also explain the -32rem left positioning? If we run your code as presented this moves everything off the screen - and the use of rem here I can't understand, is it some fix to deal with having a left side column as well?

Comment: the sidebar is  8 rem width and the navigation is 40 rem width and these  -32   rem left to hide the nav and when the user clicks on the bar icon the hidden  check gets chek and  the nav appears                       .checkbox: checked ~ .navigation{
left: 8rem;
}